# Python improper string quote

Tags: python, string, shell, quotes

Hi I am embedding a shell script in python which I wanna execute as `echo args` Where

```
args = """-ne '#!/bin/sh\n\
update_bridge_config () {\n\
    if [ $DATA_BRIDGE_IF ]; then\n\
        echo "DATA_BRIDGE_IF is $DATA_BRIDGE_IF"\n\
        sudo /usr/bin/ovs-vsctl --may-exist add-br "br-$DATA_BRIDGE_IF"\n\
    fi\n\
}\n\
ETH0_MAC_ADDR=`ip link show eth0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'`\n\
ETH1_MAC_ADDR=`ip link show eth1 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'`\n\
ETH2_MAC_ADDR=`ip link show eth2 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'`\n\ ' >> myScript.sh"""
```

When I open the file I found those particular line is getting changed as

> ETH0_MAC_ADDR= 'ip link show eth0 | awk /ether/ {print }'

Any idea what am missing ?

EDIT::  Look the **`** are getting replaced by **‘**  . And the **‘**  are missing as well as **$2**

Comment: We are missing something, as the string literal you produced includes the `$2`. Are you using this as a template somehow?

Comment: As a side note: *you don't need to explicitly add newlines*. Remove the ``\n\`` sequences at the end of each line.

Comment: Using \n just to give a good look.  But yes surprisingly $2  val is also missing

Comment: You'll need to create a reproducable sample for us; as it stands your problem cannot be reproduced with just the string definition.

Comment: " the ` are getting replaced by ‘ . And the ‘ are missing as well as $2" . No, they are not. It's useless to post only the a piece of data, claim that it was modified in an unexpected way *without* showing how you are manipulating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a single quote issue because you are starting with a single quote right after ne `"""-ne '#!/bin/sh ...` . Because of this you are not getting $2 and facing other single quote abnormalities.

Use `'"'"'` to escape `'`

> ETH0_MAC_ADDR=`ip link show eth0 | awk '"'"'/ether/ {print $2}'"'"'`

This should work. Mind it ! this issue is not pythonic but shell

Comment: Ah ! I was trying so many escape stuffs but this worked flawlessly. I don't know why some arrogant people loves to comment than answer.